# Tibco error: ClassNotFoundException: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory

Tags: classnotfoundexception, tibco, tibco-ems

I am facing this issue.
 I tested tibco with below configuration(local tibco) and it works

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactory" jndi-name="emsConnectionFactory">
    <jee:environment>
        java.naming.factory.initial=com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
        java.naming.provider.url=tibjmsnaming://localhost:7222
    </jee:environment>
</jee:jndi-lookup>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="queue" jndi-name="emsQueue">
    <jee:environment>
        java.naming.factory.initial=com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
        java.naming.provider.url=tibjmsnaming://localhost:7222
    </jee:environment>
```

But when i try to connect to the central tibco(only the provider changed) with below configuration i get classNotFound error

```
  <jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactory" jndi-name="XAQueueConnectionFactory"> 
    <jee:environment>
        java.naming.factory.initial=com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory 
        java.naming.provider.url=tcp://xsdd.xxxxxxxxx.local:8333
    </jee:environment> 
</jee:jndi-lookup> 
<jee:jndi-lookup id="queue" jndi-name="ibalance/iBatch/ReBalances">
    <jee:environment> 
        java.naming.factory.initial=com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
        java.naming.provider.url=tcp://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.local:8333
    </jee:environment>
</jee:jndi-lookup>
```

The error i am getting  is

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory 
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:46)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:654)
```

Any suggestion would be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly a classpath error. Are you running both on your local machine?

If the second one is being run on a server somewhere, ensure the EMS jar libraries are referenced in the classpath. I believe the one you're after is `tibjms.jar`.

How you reference the jar file is dependent on your environment and technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing tibjms.jar from the classpath. If any security options on the EMS server are enabled, please make sure you add tibcrypt.jar as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the TIBCO designer.
2. Open the designer.tra file located in the path C: \ tibco \ designer \ 5.10 \ bin
3. Add this path;% TRA_HOME% / lib / TIBCOjms.jar in the final part of ## this will be prepended to tibco.class.path.extended
4. Copy the accompanying booklet in the path C: \ tibco \ tra \ 5.10 \ lib
5. Ready with this should work, just start the designer and go.

download the jar is TIBCOjms.jar

Answer (score 0):

In my case, issue was very silly. There was a space at the end of class path. i.e, "com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory "