# How to post JMS message to TIBCO queue using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter tool, here I need to post xml messages to the TIBCO queue using Jmeter,
I tried something from my end but I got the below exception in the Jmeter log,
could someone help me doing this?
also I need to set the values in the xml files dynamically at runtime.

Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: 000
Response message: javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory]

Response headers:

SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like that you need to feed TIBCO jars to JMeter. As per [Tibco error: ClassNotFoundException: com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651709/tibco-error-classnotfoundexception-com-tibco-tibjms-naming-tibjmsinitialcontex) post

You'll need to put at least `tibjms.jar` to */lib* or */lib/ext* folder of your JMeter installation. JMeter restart will be required as it doesn't load jars dynamically.

It also worth checking [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) guide